# Xcode Enterprise Distribution Not Embedding Mobile Provisioning Profile

Tags: xcode, software-distribution, xcode10, enterprise-distribution

I recently updated to Xcode 10 (on accident).

Before the update, automatic code signing worked perfectly fine and the appropriate provisioning profile was embedded.

Now, after I go through the distribution wizard it generates the .ipa without embedding a provisioning profile.

When I run `ipa info` on the created .ipa, it throws:

`Embedded mobile provisioning profile not found in created.ipa`